# Rails Mongoid Buyer, Item, Purchase model associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model-associations, mongoid3

I'm using Rails 3.2 and Mongoid and I need to set up a simple purchases association. 
Current I have:

```
class Item
has_many :purchases

class Buyer
has_many :purchases

class Purchase
has_one :buyer
has_one :item
```

I'd like to be able to call all the items purchased by a given buyer which I current achieve with:
    def purchased_by(buyer_id)
      items = []
      ids = Buyer.find(buyer_id).purchase_ids
      Item.each do |i|
       items << i if (i.purchase_ids & ids).length > 0
      end
      items
    end

But this seems horribly inefficient. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
class Buyer
  def items_purchased
    purchases.collect(&:item)
  end
end
```

Then given an object `buyer`, you can get what you want by calling:

```
buyer.items_purchased
```

Comment: Nice. Works perfectly. Now I just need to figure out how to do the opposite and only show unpurchased items. Buyer.items_not_purchased... Wondering if this is the best data structure.